# Complex exponential and unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm stuck with this proof. I want to show that

$e^{ix}\in S^1$ if and only if $x \in \mathbb R$.

If $x \in \mathbb R$ then $|e^{ix}|=|\cos x + i \sin x| = \cos^2 x + \sin^2 x = 1$ therefore $e^{ix}\in S^1$ if $x$ is real.

Now for the other direction: Assume $e^{ix} \in S^1$. How can I show that $x$ must be real?

Comment: Note that $\lvert w\rvert^2 = w\overline{w}$, so $\lvert e^z\rvert^2 = e^z\overline{e^z} =\dotsc$

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, I tried that. I got 
$$ e^{iz} \overline{e^{iz}} = (\cos z + i \sin z)(\cos z - i \sin z) = \cos^2 z + \sin^2 z = 1$$

but I don't see how this implies that $z$ is real.

Comment: First, $\overline{\cos z + i \sin z} \neq \cos z - i\sin z$ generally. Then, don't rewrite it with Euler's formulae, just use what you know about the exponential function.

Comment: @DanielFischer Instead of Euler formular I should use 

$ e^z = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {z^n \over n!}$? Or the other limit definition of $\exp$ ?

Comment: Not the other limit definition. And the Taylor series only to see what $\overline{e^z}$ is. You know a bit about $e^a\cdot e^b$, use that.

Comment: @DanielFischer Is $\overline{e^{i \lambda}}$ really equal to $\sum_n (-i)^n \overline{\lambda}^n / n! = e^{-i \overline{\lambda}}$?

Comment: Yes. Conjugation is continuous, hence that holds for (convergent) series just like for finite sums.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ok, thanks to your comments I could work it out. If you don't mind please could you post these comments as an answer? I feel it's unjustified to accept someone else's answer if it didn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\lvert w\rvert^2 = w\overline{w}$, we have $\lvert e^z\rvert^2 = e^z\cdot \overline{e^z}$. Since the conjugation is a continuous field automorphism (that is, it satisfies $\overline{z+w} = \overline{z} + \overline{w}$ and $\overline{zw} = \overline{z}\cdot\overline{w}$), we have

$$\overline{e^z} = \overline{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k!}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\overline{z}^k}{k!} = e^{\overline{z}},$$

and therefore

$$\lvert e^{iz}\rvert^2 = e^{iz}\cdot e^{\overline{iz}} = e^{iz}\cdot e^{-i\,\overline{z}} = e^{i(z-\overline{z})} = e^{-2\operatorname{Im} z}.$$

So we have $\lvert e^{iz}\rvert = 1$ if and only if $e^{-2\operatorname{Im} z} = 1$, which is the case if and only if $-2\operatorname{Im} z = 0$, or, equivalently, if and only if $z\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: This is a nice answer. How do you justify the equality $\displaystyle \overline{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k!}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\overline{z}^k}{k!}$?

Comment: For the partial sums, we have $$\overline{\sum_{k=0}^N \frac{z^k}{k!}} = \sum_{k=0}^N \frac{\overline{z}^k}{k!}$$ by induction from $\overline{z+w} = \overline{z}+\overline{w}$ and $\overline{z\cdot w} = \overline{z}\cdot \overline{w}$. The continuity of the conjugation then gives $$\overline{\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^N \frac{z^k}{k!}} = \lim_{N\to\infty} \overline{\sum_{k=0}^N\frac{z^k}{k!}}.$$

Comment: Oh, right. I get it: the sequence definition of continuous function can be applied here, too. After all a series is also a sequence...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

I suggest you use the contrapositive:

If $x\not\in \Bbb R$ i.e. $x=a+ib,\;b\ne0$ prove that $e^{ix}\not\in S^1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: write $z=x+iy$ where $x$ and $y$ are real. If $e^{iz}=e^{i(x+iy)}$ has norm 1, what does that tell us about $y$?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly my question.

Comment: @newb Split this into real and imaginary parts again; you get $e^{ix-y}$. But now remember that $e^ae^b = e^{a+b}$... and take norms.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Then $iz = - \Im(z) + i\Re(z)$ (where $\Im(z)$ is the imaginary part of $z$ and $\Re(z)$, its real part). Then :

$$ \big\vert e^{iz} \big\vert = e^{-\Im(z)} $$

As a consequence :

$$ 
\begin{eqnarray*}
e^{iz} \in \mathbb{S}^{1} &\Leftrightarrow& \big\vert e^{iz} \big\vert = 1 \\[2mm] &\Leftrightarrow& \Im(z) = 0 \\[2mm]
&\Leftrightarrow& z \in \mathbb{R}
\end{eqnarray*}
$$